# Lightweight JVM Instrumentation to find unused code

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation

I was wondering if there is any lightweight way I could instrument a production JVM to gather information over a period of some months to gather statistics on unused code in my code base.

Thanks a lot for looking at this.

Comment: Do you want to find unused (or rarely used) code among among all your deployments? ( to factor out non frequent workflows, sort of pattern mining) or you want to do a dead code analysis. The latter can be easily accomplished using some static code anlayzer.

Comment: @doc_180 The way the question is formulated, I suspect it's the first one. It would be quite useful indeed, even if it just created a diff between the classes loaded and those packaged in certain JAR files.

Comment: @biziclop. I do not know of any of the shelf product that could do that. the only solution I could think of is to have an implementation of AOP and using method pointcuts to log all usage of methods and have a collection of all the methods you have in all your classses and calculate delta.

Comment: @doc_180 I don't either, but it sounds like something useful. I'd probably take the sampling approach though, instrumenting every single method is just too much of an overhead on a production environment. And if you're running it for months, I guess you could get away with one thread dump per minute.

Comment: Thanks..Pattern mining is what I am basically after..not static dead code analysis.

Answer (score 0):

File this under "experimental science project".  But the [invoke dynamic](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/) feature coming in JDK7 was used in an [interesting low-overhead test coverage prototype](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/forax/archive/2011/02/12/jsr-292-goodness-fast-code-coverage-tool-less-10k).

Maybe a bit too bleeding-edge today, but interesting once Java 7 is out.